How to move AR object to the corner of the camera?
I am using Vuforia for Unity in android, here is what I did, I want to move my AR object that is in a MidAirStage to move to the top left corner of the screen.
If I mode the object in the editor to the cordinates printed the position is correct however when I call the method at runtime the object moves to a completly differnt position. What am I doing wrong? Open to other solutions as well. Thank you.
private void UpdateModelPosition()
        {
             Bounds _bounds = loadedModel.GetComponentInChildren<MeshFilter>().mesh.bounds;
            
             // Move model to the center of pivot.
             loadedModel.transform.SetParent(modelPivot.transform);
             loadedModel.transform.position -= _bounds.center - loadedModel.transform.position;
            
             // Move model to the correct corner of pivot.
             float _widthSize = _bounds.size.x;
             float _newX = 0;
             float _heightSize = _bounds.size.y;
             float _newY = 0;
              switch (ModelPosition)
              {
                  case ModelPositionType.TopLeft:
                      _newX += -_widthSize / 2;
                      _newY += -_heightSize / 2;
                      break;
                  case ModelPositionType.TopMiddle:
                      _newY += -_heightSize / 2;
                      break;
                  case ModelPositionType.TopRight:
                      _newX += _widthSize / 2;
                      _newY += -_heightSize / 2;
                      break;
                  case ModelPositionType.MiddleLeft:
                      _newX += -_widthSize / 2;
                      break;
                  case ModelPositionType.MiddleRight:
                      _newX += _widthSize / 2;
                      break;
                  case ModelPositionType.BottomLeft:
                      _newX += -_widthSize / 2;
                      _newY += _heightSize / 2;
                      break;
                  case ModelPositionType.BottomMiddle:
                      _newY += _heightSize / 2;
                      break;
                  case ModelPositionType.BottomRight:
                      _newX += _widthSize / 2;
                      _newY += _heightSize / 2;
                      break;
                  case  ModelPositionType.Custom:
                      _newX += _widthSize / 2;
                      _newY += -_heightSize / 2;
                      break;
             }
             loadedModel.transform.position = new Vector3(loadedModel.transform.position.x + _newX, loadedModel.transform.position.y + _newY, 0);
            modelPivot.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
            
            //Move pivot to the correct screen corner.
            Camera _camera = videoRecorderController.NotRecordingCamera;
            float _screenHeight = Screen.height;
            float _screenWidth = Screen.width;
            float _screenDepth = loadedModel.transform.position.z - _camera.transform.position.z;
            Vector3 _screenToWorldPoint = _camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, _screenHeight, _screenDepth)); // Top left corner.
            loadedModel.transform.position = new Vector3(_screenToWorldPoint.x, _screenToWorldPoint.y, loadedModel.transform.position.z);
            
            Debug.Log(_screenToWorldPoint);
        }

